# Add objects to list on or after creation

Tags: java, arraylist

In java I would like to have every object created, added to a list of objectsamples.
Is there a way to do it in the constructor itself like:

```
public ObjectSample() {
    mObjectSamples.add(this);
}
```

or do I have to call the add method after creation.

Comment: You can do either, but realize that if done inside of the constructor, the object is not yet fully realized until the constructor has completed. That may have problems if you try to use the object in the list before the constructor has completed. I wonder if you really want to use a factory of some sort for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the constructor of `Object` class.

You can have a constructor in one of your classes that adds the newly created instance to a static Collection.

```
public YourClass 
{
    public static List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public YourClass()
    {
        list.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, Object was used as a sample, thats why I changed it, but adding a uninitialized object to the list was not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new instance of you object to the list.

```
public class Foo{

    public static List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
    public Foo(){
        //Do whatever
    }

    public stativ void main(String args[]){
        list.add(new Foo());
    }

}
```

This will add the object to the list by passing a new instance as an argument to the `add()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Create you object first then add this object to `List`,

```
class MyClass{

    private static List<Object> mObjectSamples = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
    private int a,b;

      MyClass(int a, int b){  // initialize your object using parametrized constructor
       this.a = a;  // suppose you have to initialize you a and b member of class.
       this.b= b;
       mObjectSamples.add(this);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot modify the constructor of a library class, especially not the one of `Object`. However, I absolutely do not recommend putting *every* new Object in a list anyway, since there is an enourmous amount of objects that you do not even need to care about, and I can't think of any case where you would want to put all of them in a list.

If you want every object of a specific type, e.g. `Element` in your list, you could simply define the `Element` class like this:

```
public class Element
{
    public Element()
    {
        elements.add(this);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a static factory method, as recommended by Joshua Block's *Effective Java*, and also described in [this Baeldung post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructors-vs-static-factory-methods). If you make the constructor private, then your class can only be instantiated by the static factory method. It's often a good idea to limit constructors to doing the instantiation of an object's class-specified fields, and let a more general bit of code handle anything outside the class. A static factory method is one good place to put such external instantiation.

For the notional Element class, it might look like this:

```
public class Element {
    private final List<Element> trackedElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Element newTrackedElement(...) {
        var e = new Element(...);
        trackedElements.add(e);
        ...other out-of-class instantiation...
        return e;
    }

    private Element(...) {
        ...in-class instantiation...
    }
    ...
}
```

With this approach, the collection only contains fully-instantiated objects, and those objects are guaranteed to be in the collection by the time the factory method call completes. It's simpler than having a fully-implemented factory class, which could be useful if there's enough extra work involved in creating the new object.